# SharePoint Online Team Site Top Navigation with Drop Down Menu

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, navigation, modern-team-site, top-navigation

Is there a way for Team Site to generate top quick launch with drop down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft is rolling out new navigation features for SharePoint team sites using which you can fulfill your requirements.

This new feature allows:

1. Change site navigation orientation from Vertical to Horizontal
2. Set Mega menu navigation for team sites in Horizontal orientation
3. Turn site navigation ON/OFF

You can find more details at: [New Navigation features for SharePoint team sites](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/09/17/new-navigation-features-for-sharepoint-team-sites/)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the sharing. With this, does it mean I can only have one navigation menu, instead of another customised navigation?

Comment: Using this feature you can move vertical (left side) menu to top side in horizontal way, same like communication site top navigation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a Modern Team site in SPO to have a Top Nav, you can make it a Hub Site through the SPO Admin Center or PowerShell. That will give you access to the same navigation nodes you'd see in a standard Communication site.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, this could be one of the way. But I do not have access to admin center.